# when append a <a>, my click function doesnt work

Tags: jquery

when you click on my link #addScnt, a new child appears. Everything works fine so far but I append another  tag and when you click on it, there is supposed to be something happen but as you can guess, nothing happens...but when I create another link inside my page (so outside my jquery function) my click function works... So I doesn't understand what's going on there.

```
$(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

    $('#addScnt').click(function() {
        $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="file" id="p_scnt" name="p_scnt_' + i +'"></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
        i++;
        return false;
    });

    $('#remScnt').click(function() {
        alert();
    });

});
```

my html

```
 <h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Ajoutez une nouvelle photo</a></h2>

<div id="p_scents">
    <p>
        <label for="p_scnts">
            <input type="file" id="p_scnt" name="p_scnt">
        </label>
    </p>
</div>
```

So, $('#remScnt').click(function() doesnt work at all when I add another child...but If I literally put a  tag with the id #remScnt on my page, my alert will work...

Comment: double #ids spotted...

Comment: It might be useful for you to readup some HTML tutorials, you're making some rookie mistakes here and you might save yourself a headache

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things are going on here...

First, it looks like you're re-using `id` values.  If you're adding this multiple times to the page:

```
<a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a>
```

Then you have multiple elements with the same `id`, which is invalid.  So the behavior of things like jQuery selectors (`$('#remScnt')`) are undefined.  (They may *coincidentally* work, but it's still invalid and undefined.)  Instead, try using classes instead:

```
<a href="#" class="remScnt">Remove</a>
```

and:

```
$('.remScnt')
```

Second, the click binding here happens only *once* when the page loads:

```
$('.remScnt').click(function() {
    // etc.
});
```

Bindings are attached to *elements*, not to *selectors*.  So it will only work for elements which exist at the time the binding is created.  Elements added to the page afterward won't have anything attached to their click events.

You can get around this by [delegating the event handler to a common parent, and filtering events based on the selector](http://publicvoidlife.blogspot.com/2014/03/on-on-or-event-delegation-explained.html).  jQuery provides the `.on()` function for this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.remScnt', function() {
    // etc.
});
```

What this does is actually bind to the click event of the entire *document*, and respond to that event any time something matching the provided selector invokes such an event.  So put it simply, in this version the `'.remScnt'` selector is evaluated when the click event happens, rather than when the event handler is defined.

You don't need to use `document` to hold the event, any common parent would work.  As long as that parent element isn't dynamically added/removed like the target elements.  For example, if all of the target `a class="remScnt"` elements are going to be in the same `div`, then you can target that `div` instead:

```
$('#someParentDiv').on('click', '.remScnt', function() {
    // etc.
});
```

Comment: Wow. For the first part, I did see my mistakes but even changing to classes didn't do anything. But now that I tried that on function, everything was smoothly working. Really great explanation, clear, and clean. Thank you for your time, David!

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you only use each ID once, and use event delegation for dynamically created elements. Try:

```
$('#p_scents').on('click', '#remScnt', function() {
    alert();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you append an element you need to use .on like this,

```
$('#p_scents').on('click', '#remScnt', function(){
    // Some Stuff
});
```